# New Swift Application Creates Obj C Files

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a bit new to iOS development. Am I going crazy here?

I am using xCode to create a paged application. I select new project with the language as swift.

When I go to add a new view to the application it adds a view with Objective C?? Why? I want to use Swift. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Adding more screenshots, how do I get the second view to show me the Swift code instead of the "UIKit" code?

Working Side...
[image]

Not working

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyVlP.png): [image]

Comment: The underlying frameworks (UIKit, in your example) are written in Objective-C. They're not being *created*, simply *referenced*.

Comment: @Fattie There's nothing wrong. That is `UIViewController.h`. That's from UIKit. That is not being created as part of the project.

Comment: How do I view the swift code then??? All I see is the .h file

Comment: The file that is created is totally a objective c file its .xib

Comment: @Xogle You can't see Swift code for SDK provided frameworks. You only get Swift code for your own classes.

Comment: I don't think anyone is really understanding, when I make a new view, THAT is the file that is created, I don't get a swift file when I click on the code and view view I don't get a swift file and its no where to be found

Comment: it looks like @aaplmath has explained it, phew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Assistant Editor is automatically opening the underlying Objective-C header files rather than the Swift files associated with your View Controllers. Try clicking on `Automatic` at the top of the Assistant editor, then hovering for a moment to see if your Swift file comes up (it should appear above or below the `UIViewController.h` file).

If you haven't created a subclass for the View Controller you've created in the storyboard, you'll need to do that first, then assign that class to the View Controller in the storyboard. To do this, select `File` > `New` > `File…`, select `Cocoa Touch Class`, and make it a subclass of `UIViewController` (don't create a XIB file). Then, in your storyboard, click on your newly-created View Controller (you can select it from within the view hierarchy on the left), open the Identity inspector, and set its `Class` to the subclass of `UIViewController` you just created.

If, for some reason, you've created a View Controller class and correctly associated it with the storyboard object and it's still not appearing, you can use the `Manual` selection in the Assistant editor to drill down to the file you want to appear.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful detailed answer. This was the key. Not sure why they have the prebuilt view classes that you can drag and drop if it falls completely on its face...

Comment: @Xogle As I wrote, you need to click on the storyboard in the view hierarchy (it's got a yellow circle next to it), open the Identity inspector (in the menu bar: View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector) and under `Custom Class` set the `Class` to the subclass you just created.

Comment: I SEE you have to do it with a new one, I got it now. THANKS!